# Why isnt my sound working? Is this probably a bug?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im using some sounds in my unity game but they dont play, if i check out 
the stats it says the volume is -60dB

I have the Unity version 2018.4.11f1

```
void Start()
{
    muerteEnemigo = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("muerteEnemigo");
    Disparo = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("Disparo");
    muerteJugador = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("muerteJugador");

    audioSrc = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}
public static AudioClip Disparo, muerteEnemigo, muerteJugador;
static AudioSource audioSrc;

public static void Playsound(string clip)
{

    switch (clip)
    {
        case "Disparo":
            audioSrc.PlayOneShot(Disparo);
            break;

    }
    switch (clip)
    {
        case "muerteEnemigo":
            audioSrc.PlayOneShot(muerteEnemigo);
            break;

    }
    switch (clip)
    {
        case "muerteJugador":
            audioSrc.PlayOneShot(muerteJugador);
            break;

    }
```

and the more I try I dont get a way to get the sound to play, would it be a bug frum unity?

Comment: Try setting the volume of your audio clips in the inspector.

Comment: did you attach 'AudioListener' on the same scene?

Comment: Was there any log in the console when you tried to play the sounds?

Comment: Have you done some debugging to show your Playsound being called?